# C# - Add multiple elements to an IList in one line

Tags: java, c#, list, arraylist

I am able to do this in one line using Java.

**Java:**

```
List<WebElement> colElements;
WebElement rowElement;

//some code

colElements.addAll(rowElement.findElements(By.tagName("td")));
```

**C#:**

```
IList<IWebElement> colElements;
IWebElement rowElement;

//some code

colElements.addAll(rowElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));
```

Clearly, there isn't a method called addAll in the IList interface in C#.

I'm hoping there is another way to do this in one line.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That you want is the `AddRange` method.

```
colElements.AddRange(rowElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td")));
```

For further documentation about this method, please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: That's only available in the List class and not the IList interface which I am using here.

Comment: @John is there a particular reason you're using `IList` over `List`?

Comment: Yeah but i suppose that you should have initialized a list to add your elements. Otherwise where could you add your elements? A list implements the `IList` interface.

Comment: I need to use an IList, else my other code: `colElements = rowElement.FindElements(By.TagName("th"));` wont work.

Comment: @John what error does it throw if any? `List` implements `IList`, `List` should always be preferred unless you're exposing your code in a framework or something?

Comment: Changing colElements to a List gives this: _cannot implicitly convert.. object model to ..generic list_ And yes, I am using several external frameworks too.